# Office 2007 compatibility pack not working on some PCs

Tags: microsoft-office

After installing the Office 2007 file converter on PCs running Office 2003 some work and some don't. The error I am getting is the same as this person [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/MS_Office/Excel/Q_24280438.html). I also logged on as admin and after re-installing, it works under admin but not as user.

Answer (score 0):

What Service Pack of Office 2003 are you running, and are you installing the latest Service Pack version of the Compatibility Pack?

It's a while since I've dealt with it, but I seem to remember there was an Office 2003 service pack pre-req, and that the Compatibility Pack has itself been through a service pack or two.

Comment: I've seen this quite a few times, and the steps to resolve were always convoluted.